# SB X-FI Problem on 12.04 LTS

Tags: sound-blaster

I set 5.1 on the sound options under Ubuntu, but I don't get centerbox and subwoofer output when I click to the test buttons (soundspeakers grafiks).

When I work under Win 7 every speakers works properly.

How can I improve or check my drivers of Ubuntu? Is there a Driver from Alsa I can use it to get work all speakers (5.1) under Ubuntu?

Please HELP, I don't have knowledge on Ubuntu quite well.

Comment: Welcome Paul, Have a look at this Q&A it might help you. We will probably need more details to help you more http://askubuntu.com/questions/20432/has-anyone-got-creative-soundblaster-x-fi-surround-5-1-pro-usb-interface-i?rq=1

Comment: Yes I have but it does not help me, thanks at all.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. In my case was solution very simply.  Centerbox and subwoofer output was muted only (this was the default state after Ubuntu 12.04 installation). That's why I don't get centerbox and subwoofer output when I click to the test buttons.

Open Terminal and run the command `alsamixer`. Find your SB card (key <kbd>F6</kbd>) and check if the columns “Surround” and “Center/L” are set to `OO (MM = mute)`. It has to be set to `OO` if you want to hear output. You can turn on or mute selected output by pressing <kbd>M</kbd>.

Tip: Change Terminal help from <kbd>F1</kbd> to some other key. Only then <kbd>F1</kbd> would be assigned as a shortcut for Help for `alsamixer`.